# Saving data to a local text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// Queries atlatlsoftware.com and returns the site in json data format, using YQL
$.ajax({
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fatlatlsoftware.com%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22desktop-footer%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%5B2%5D%2Ftd%5B1%5D'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    // upon success, logs the data as "response"
    success: function (response) {

        // simply following the json data path and assigning it to a variable
        var address = response.query.results.td.div[1].content;
        var phone = response.query.results.td.div[2];
        var email = response.query.results.td.div[3];
        // var tweet = response.query.results;

        // appends the variable to the html
        $(".address").html(address);
        $(".phone").html(phone);
        $(".email").html(email);
        console.log(address);
        console.log(phone);
        console.log(email);
        // console.log(tweet);

    }
});
```

The script above pulls in an address, email, and phone number from a website.  How can i simply save this data that i pull in to a text file?

Im trying to do [this](https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/) but without having a to use a click event

Comment: *"Im trying to do this but without having a to use a click event"* Questions on SO must be self-contained. If you're going to refer to something outside the question, you **must** summarize it **in** the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, neither Firefox nor Chrome requires that the code in your linked article's `saveTextAsFile` be run in response to a user event. (Which is horrifying and almost certainly a bug.) So just adapt the example so you call `saveTextAsFile` from within your `ajax` completion handler.